# jQuery: show ajax returned message in a message box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used to use the follow AJAX to update the `content` div with the returned message. Now I would like to display the message in a pop-up message box instead, and the user would click a button to close the box. Is there a **simple** way of doing it and how? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(message) {
    $('#content').html(message);
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly launch the popup after replacing the popup div content with your `message`

Comment: what about `alert(message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(message) {
    //$('#content').html(message);
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: That simple? Oh mine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make a div on page. keep it's display none initially...and then fill data and show it

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">
  This a vertically and horizontally centered popup.
</div>


<style type="text/css">
  .popup {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-50px 0 0 -100px; /* [-(height/2)px 0 0 -(width/2)px] */
    display:none;
  }
</style>


  $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(message) {

        $('.popup').html(message);
        $('.popup').show()
      }); 
    });
```